# Autofac Constructor Injection by Attribute

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, attributes, inversion-of-control, autofac

I have a class that currently takes an `IIndex` in order to select an indexed dependency. I'd like to change that to somehow using an attribute on the constructor argument, in order to directly specify which one to use.

I'm pretty sure Autofac doesn't support this natively, but I'm not afraid to write my own attribute for this. I've messed around with the source side of Autofac before (custom registration sources, etc.) but I've never seen a way of tailoring the injection side. Can anyone help?

P.S.: I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477613/resolve-dependency-with-autofac-based-on-constructor-parameter-attribute) but it turned into a discussion on the benefits of attribute-based injection. OTOH, I already decided I don't want to have to manually register each one of my types that depends on this particular dependency one-by-one, so I'd prefer it.

Comment: Does [this blogpost](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/01/09/MetadataRoleHint.aspx) help you? If not could you add a small example how the `IIndex` is currently used, and some pseudo-code of how you would like it to become?

Comment: [I posted something like this in a previous question. Give it a try.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14124961/540663

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by scanning your class metadata on resolving an interface. When you get info about its parameters you can resolve actual implementation of the interface. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19056430/974487).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/WebFormsIntegration says we can create a Custom Dependency Injection Models by implementing IInjectionBehaviour, I think it worth a try.