# Autofac get decorated QueryHandler by convention based on constructor parameter name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, decorator, autofac

We inject `IQueryHandler<TQUery,TResult>` into our MVC controllers. We globally register all of these in the container

We have written a decorator that can cache the results of `IQueryHandler`.

We want to sometimes get cached reults and other times not from the same handler.

Is it possible to conditionally get a decorated handler based on the name of the constructor parameter. e.g. inject `IQueryHandler<UnemployedQuery, IEnumerable<People>> cachedPeopleHandler` if we prefix constructor parameter name with cached we actually get it wrapped with decorator?

Just trying to use a more convention over configuration approach to simplify things.

Comment: So you want to have a query handler that gets decorated when injected in one class, but not decorated when injected in another class, simply based on the parameter name of the consuming class? You might want to think about a different approach, because that would be extremely difficult to achieve. Even with Simple Injector (that has much better support for applying decorators conditionally) this would be quite hard to achieve.

Comment: @Steven It's not so extremely difficult)), see my answer below. And I agree with you, it's better to think about a different approach.

Comment: @Steven makes a change when something decorator related is hard SI however it is off the wall way of doing it. I just thought it would be an easy to apply solution. It doesn't have to be configured that way but we need some way of getting queries cached and uncached. Wanted minimal setup and something convention based.

Comment: @GraemeMiller: Do you really need the same query to be both cached and uncached at the same time (depending on the consumer)? That seems like an odd requirement. Why do you need that?

Comment: @Steven public side of system can use hours old data. Internal side must have latest data. Lots of identical identical queries and don't want to have to invalidate

Comment: @GraemeMiller: But in that case, shouldn't it be wiser to split the application in to separate applications, or one app with multiple configurations and give each configuration its own application instance?

Comment: They currently share a lot of stuff e.g. views etc and pulling it all apart would be a bit of a refactor. Probably agree though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible to do it. Below is a simple working example on how you can achieve it:

```
class Program
{
    public interface IQueryHandler{}

    private class QueryHandler : IQueryHandler
    {
    }

    private class CacheQueryHandler : IQueryHandler
    {
    }

    public interface IService
    {
    }

    private class Service : IService
    {
        private readonly IQueryHandler _queryHandler;
        private readonly IQueryHandler _cacheQueryHandler;

        public Service(IQueryHandler queryHandler, IQueryHandler cacheQueryHandler)
        {
            _queryHandler = queryHandler;
            _cacheQueryHandler = cacheQueryHandler;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("_queryHandler is {0}; _cacheQueryHandler is {1}", _queryHandler,
                _cacheQueryHandler);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        // Register the dependency
        builder.RegisterType<QueryHandler>().As<IQueryHandler>();
        // Register the decorator of the dependency
        builder.RegisterType<CacheQueryHandler>().Keyed<IQueryHandler>("cache");

        // Register the service implementation
        builder.RegisterType<Service>().AsSelf();

        // Register the interface of the service
        builder.Register(c =>
        {
            var ctor = typeof (Service).GetConstructors()[0];

            var parameters =
                ctor.GetParameters()
                    .Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("cache"))
                    .Select(p => new NamedParameter(p.Name, c.ResolveKeyed("cache", p.ParameterType)));

            return c.Resolve<Service>(parameters);
        }).As<IService>();

        using (var container = builder.Build())
        {
            var service = container.Resolve<IService>();
            Console.WriteLine(service.ToString());

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

**Update:**
Basically you need to:
1. Think up a general convention. Prefix "cache" of ctor parameter name in your case.
2. Register your dependencies as usual.
3. Register your decorators, so they don't overwrite your original dependencies and you can easily resolve them basing on your convention. e.g. Keyed, Named, via Attribute, etc.
4. Register you actual implementation of class that uses decorators
5. Register your interface that describes the class via lambda expression that has all magic inside.

Note: I provided just a simple and working example. It's on you to make it nice, easy to use and fast e.g. make it as an extension, generic, cache reflection results etc. It's not difficult anyway.
Thanks.

Comment: This is probably not what the OP is looking for for several reasons. 1. We're dealing with conditionally applied decorators here. The caching decorator is probably not the only decorator that is applied here and they will probably be stacked differently for each implementation. 2. We're (most likely) dealing with a lot of `IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>` implementations and a lot of consumers that take a dependency on that interface. This will mean your composition root will become a maintenance nightmare. 3. Performance will drop considerably.

Comment: @Steven Ahh, common, do you want me to write nice and production ready code here?)) I showed a simple working example on how you can achieve it. It's fully on TS to think up a convention, make registration generic, write an extension for ContainerBuilder, cache reflection results, etc. I thought you understand that))